# Want to convert this Bumper Javascript to C#. Unity3d Game development

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
var bumperForce : float = 10;

function OnCollisionEnter(collision : Collision) {
for (var contact : ContactPoint in collision.contacts) {

   contact.otherCollider.rigidbody.AddForce( -5 * contact.normal * bumperForce,  ForceMode.Impulse);

 }
}
```

Gamemanager is being used in game to bring audio. Although an object named "Bumper" has no audio, even though its present in game manager. I am assuming thats because its a Javascript rather than a C# file like others.

I nee help converting above bumper script so I can use Gamemanager to assign sound to this object.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
public float bumperForce = 10;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
   foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts) {
      contact.otherCollider.rigidbody.AddForce( -5 * contact.normal * bumperForce,  ForceMode.Impulse);
   }
}
```

Comment: its giving me this error- Assets/Script/Bumper/Bumper.cs(1,14): error CS0116: A namespace can only contain types and namespace declarations

Comment: same error again. Is has something to do with Float maybe?

Comment: no. i tried here and it works. I only changed `for` with `foreach`

Comment: Actually the javascript works fine. I just wanted to make bumper sound work when ball collides with it.   Btw i found out why my sound was not working. I forgot to tick "Is Trigger"

Comment: nvm i think i am ok with javascript. thanks for help

Comment: Nvm i have figured out how to make an object as bumper,attaching script,IsTrigger = on, and putting a collider of same shape with audio attched to it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a website that converts unityscrpit to C# scripts, you can take a look from 
[here](http://files.m2h.nl//js_to_c.php).